# Socket.io send data specific to each user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What is the best method to send user specific data from node server to client using socket io. Should I create each socket connections for users (probably hit the performance) or should I open each channel based on user.

----- Update on 09/16/2014-----

Recently i have tried creating multiple rooms corresponding to each userid based on login and in the UI layer i'm only getting user specific data. Everything works fine.

But if we look into Chrome Web Developer Websocket tab and click  the connection  and Frames subtab i could still see other user data. Does this means we have to spin off different socket connection for each user rather than creating rooms for user.

I have broadcasted data for 3 id

```
1.starts with dGhvY
2.starts with bnZIZ
3.starts with dXZIb
```

Please find screenshot to get more idea[image]

Comment: you can use socket IDs to send data to a specific user

Comment: One thing i found is same user can have multiple socket connections, if new tab or different device is used. Then its another task to emit data to multiple active socket session of a user.

Comment: Then you can use rooms. Based on some kind of user ID, you can put put the same user from different devices or tabs in a unique room and then you can emit to that room.